# Disabling site template in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template

I need to disable few options while creating a sub site. While creating a site, we have to select an option from template selection. So there I need to disable all the templates and custom templates should only be enabled.

Is there an OOB way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Activate Publishing features if not already activated.

   - SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure - Site collection feature
   - SharePoint Server Publishing - Site feature
2. Go to **Site Settings** --> **Page layouts and site templates**(under Look and Feel)
3. In Subsite Templates section , select **Subsites can only use the following site templates**:
   Add your custom templates and click **OK**.
   [image]